# QThread::create appears to not pass argument to function

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I have a function that I want to execute within a thread. Looks like this:

```
QThread* thread = QThread::create([](std::string nameString, std::string pth){zipUtils::unzip_v2(nameString.c_str(), pth.c_str());},
            filePath.toStdString(), extP);
```

To make sure my arguments actually get to the function as they should, I print them inside of it, and as a result, I found that the second argument (`extP.c_str()`), prints as some sort of garbage (just a few symbols and letters, usually up to three, not very long) instead of what it should be. What could the problem be? Strangely, the first value is just fine, the second one seems to be problematic.

Comment: QtConcurrentRun http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/qtconcurrentrun.html

Comment: Oh, great, that seemed to do the trick. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
QtConcurrent::run(myObject, &MyObject::update, arg1);
```

The line above executes in asynchronous (parallel mode) the function **update()** in the class **MyObject** passing to it **arg1**

in your case you should have something like this:

```
QtConcurrent::run(zipUtils, &ZipUtils::unzip_v2, nameString.c_str(), pth.c_str());
```